# Had the love overflowed to the servers?

Tags: discussion, support, offline

Meta.SO was just offline (like 60 seconds, if that). Was this planned? Or is the LoveOverflowing? Or was it just me?

Explanation:

> [image]

And the [Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?)

Comment: Yes, we planned to take the site down. Come on. :P

Comment: ME!  It was all me.  I was on the wrong machine when I typed a command.  --Tom Limoncelli, Stack Exchange SRE.

Comment: Ohmigosh, meta was down for *60* seconds? OH NO, THE WORLD'S COMING TO AN END!!!111

Comment: Hey, we might have a [lot of spare server power](http://stackexchange.com/performance), but there's a ***lot*** of extra love that they're having to contend with today.  These things happen.

Comment: @Tom that's worth an answer and tons of precious MSE repz!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improvements to site status and incident communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378941/improvements-to-site-status-and-incident-communication)

Comment: @Rob are we supposed to be closing off outage posts as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Tim, 3 others chose [no repro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/83763) which may not be as helpful (after 7 years) as the information provided by my link. Now there's a site you can check before reporting, to determine if it was scheduled or is unannounced but they are aware of a problem. If you prefer a humorous answer there is this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51213/282094 - Technically, leave open is the correct review.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I'm Tom Limoncelli and I'm an SRE here at Stack Exchange.

Yes, we had a 30-60 second blip just a little while ago.  Why?  Because I typed a command on the wrong machine.

Boy do I feel stupid.

Yes, I'm taking precautions to prevent that kind of mistake in the future.

Sufficiently humbled,
Tom Limoncelli, SRE

Comment: THIS GUY DID IT!!

Comment: Full disclaimer: I accidentally rebooted several secondary Colorado web tier machines last week. And by several I mean all. And by Colorado I mean New York. And by secondary I mean primary.

Comment: Whatever happened to the postmortems for the May outages? (ref: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/595722551004942336)

Comment: Lets not forget the LB i rebooted last week too... also long ago something, something BGP config, something something.

Comment: So this became the unofficial Team Shame Board? ;)

Comment: We have already deducted the appropriate amount from his next paycheck as per SRE official policies for being the root cause of an outage.

Comment: Paid?  You told me we were all volunteers!  Some of you get paid?

Comment: Wait, it's free? Why am I paying for this job?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's called Team Building thank you very much.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that SRE stands for "Sorta Reboots Everything"?

Comment: ...what does SRE mean...?

Comment: For the curious, SRE stands for [Site Reliability Engineer](http://googleforstudents.blogspot.com/2012/06/site-reliability-engineers-worlds-most.html) :)

Comment: @NickCraver It could have been worse, it could have been Colorade **and** New York.

Comment: @NickCraver Ah, I presumed SRE was Site Reboot Engineer

Comment: @TomLimoncelli "*Because I typed a command on the wrong machine*" Which *other* Stack Overflow site was *ok* to take down :D

Comment: @ɥʇǝS care to explain why it's proper grammar? Found no evidence [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an) and neither [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms), as far as I can tell "S" is not a vowel.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When it comes to acronyms it depends on how they are *pronounced*. SRE is pronounced *ess-arr-ee*, which clearly starts with a vowel sound :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard it has nothing to do with how it's written and everything to do with how it's pronounced. See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an/164#164), for example,  or [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/591/01/), or [here](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Writing/a.html).

Comment: I don't understand. Is this an unofficial plan of the SE company, or this is an individual rebels the official direction of the company?

Comment: Wish I got 1k rep every time I did something boneheaded at work... :)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Usually I'm live-and-let-live with regard to spelling and grammar, but seeing as your revision comment made specific reference to it, please allow me to point out that it's "let's" and not "lets".

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Aha! Someone found my easter egg! I was waiting for that ;p Actually, I only changed it because the original revision had it correct but it was erroneously changes (in a single edit for that matter). I'm sorry if you took my comment too seriously.

Comment: Sorry, I really am sorry, but I had to...  http://devopsreactions.tumblr.com/post/123358501965/using-the-right-command-on-the-wrong