# "modified" instead of "answered" in home page - probably due to grace period editing

Tags: bug, homepage, grace-period, last-activity

The home page list shows the "modified" label, and linking to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259523/had-the-love-overflowed-to-the-servers/259527#259527) as last activity.

> [image]

However, the answer is not modified:

> [image]

I also took a look in the answer's [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/259527/revisions) but nothing in there - just the initial revision.

I can only assume that edit during the grace period was taken into account, while it shouldn't.

Comment: I noticed this twice or thrice on chem.SE too.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani yeah, most likely it's affecting all the sites

Comment: Okay, who typed a command on the wrong machine *this* time? Seriously, though, I've noticed this, too.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha. I bet it was... someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no bug... well maybe.

There is a grace period after you post your post where revisions made to your post during that time will ***not*** show up in your post's revision history. This can happen in all sites and seemingly, they kinda forgot to imply that when speaking of the answer's label... So you are right Shadow Wizard.

Well there is no indication of the post being revised, it probably was. So the label shows "modified". That "modified" label needs to changed to "answered". If not, what's the use of the grace period of "secret revising" if people know that the owner did revise the post anyways? So I say fix that to "answered".