# The expanded view for recently active posts says "modified" on any activity

Tags: bug, new-nav

That's what you see when you go to [the recently active questions and choose the expanded view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?sort=recentlyactive&tagFilter=all&layout=expanded):

> [image]

I agree, the question was modified by being answered, though this kind of activity was always displayed as "answered", as can still be seen in [the compact view of the same recently active questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?sort=recentlyactive&tagFilter=all&layout=compact):

> [image]

Same for "asked" being replaced by "modified" - which is not correct in this case, if the post hasn't been modified since asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["modified" instead of "answered" in home page - probably due to grace period editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259531/modified-instead-of-answered-in-home-page-probably-due-to-grace-period-edi)

Comment: @Rene not the case at all. Go to my first link and compare with the second.

Comment: The result is the same, isn't it? The distinction between the initial action and subsequent actions is gone. Maybe there are different paths to get a similar outcome but I expect this to be the same bug. If you have nothing more than *not the case at all* my duplicate vote stands.

Comment: @Rene Sha has shown an example from the compact layout which says modified instead of answered. In my question, the compact layout functions correctly, look at the second screenshot. The problems is with the expanded layout.

Comment: And we really need a new bug report for this? Couldn't the one from Sha be extended to include the expanded layout as well? You know where to find him...

Comment: @rene Oh, we really need it, because these bug reports are unrelated. Okay. In Sha's case, only one post was claimed to be modified instead of answered, and seemingly incorrectly. This is not the case in my question. My question reports a bug which says all the events are replaced with "modified", and in another layout. All the events, not just a randomly picked one.

Comment: I give in... mission accomplished...